# SpriteKit - SKSpriteNode physicsBody not forming to CGPath

Tags: objective-c, sprite, sprite-kit

I have an `SKSpriteNode` that looks like a trapezoid, with the code like this:

```
bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(90, 90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(374, 90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(462, 0)];

CGPathRef path2 = bezierPath.CGPath;
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path2];
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

I remember reading somewhere that an SKSpriteNode must be convex, and this shape certainly seems convex. What happens in the program is, when a vehicle runs over this trapezoid shaped bump, what seems to happen is that the vehicle goes below the trapezoid shape. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's clockwise winding; it needs to be counterclockwise. Reverse the order of your points.

Comment: Isn't that more for path fill rules? I'd be interested to see if that applies here too. I'm guessing using `closePath` might fix the issue, or it is a coordinate system positioning problem.

Comment: It's for collisions too. From the SKPhysicsBody docs: "A convex polygonal path with counterclockwise winding and no self intersections. The points are specified relative to the owning node’s origin."  This directional requirement is common in other physics engines too, such as Chipmunk.

Comment: I just did what you suggested, and it seems to be producing the same effect. I also changed the bezierPath to a regular CGMutablePathRef

Comment: I would double-check that the physics shape is anchored to the visuals coordinates properly. Too many times I've had sprites show in one place, and the physics offset to one side.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. Is there any way to draw this physics body to the scene, so I can position it correctly? or is there another way?

Comment: and how exactly does one go about anchoring PhysicsBodies?

Comment: My god, I'm a moron. Just realized the anchor point was incorrect and my points are invalid. Cheers!